# how to treat binary variables when normalizing for DL model?

Tags: neural-networks, normalization, z-score, data-preprocessing

So I am doing preprocessing for deep learning model. I have mix of binary and continuous variables. I will normalize continuous variables to z-scores (to standard normal distribution). Should I "normalize" also binary variables, or should I keep them at 0 an 1 ? (I am doing binary classification, hidden units have selu activation and output is sigmoid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[0,1] are just fine. If you want you can change them to boolean.